# Simple "get letter of the alphabet via number" code doesn't work for "z"?

Tags: python

I'm newly learning Python for school, I have wrote this code as training; it works fine except for the last letter "z".

Ther code is this:

```
alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

letter = int(input('Input number of letter needed from alphabet (between 1 and 26): '))

if 0 < letter < len(alpha):
    print(alpha[letter - 1])

elif letter <= 0:
    print ('Number is smaller than number of letters in the alphabet.')

elif letter > len(alpha):
    print ("Number is larger than number of letters in the alphabet")
```

It works fine, but when I enter "26" which is for "z", it gives me null instead of an error or "z".
Test it [here](https://www.online-python.com/).

Comment: You have an off-by-1 error.  It's because `len(alpha)` is 26 and "26 < 26" is false.  Use `letter-1` in your `if` statement.

Comment: `26` is equal to `len(alpha)`, not smaller. It should be `<= len(alpha)`

Answer (score 0):

You must include "=" in fisrt if statement:

```
alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

letter = int(input('Input number of letter needed from alphabet (between 1 and 26): '))

if 0 < letter <= len(alpha):
 print(alpha[letter - 1])

elif letter <= 0:
 print ('Number is smaller than number of letters in the alphabet.')

elif letter > len(alpha):
 print ("Number is larger than number of letters in the alphabet")
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to change `if 0 < letter < len(alpha):` to `if 0 < letter <= len(alpha):` as this drops the case where letter = len(alpha), which is for the letter 'z'

bonus: you can write a one-liner for it if you know what ASCII is (assuming the input is valid though)

```py
print(chr(96 + int(input())))
```